# Function produces incorrect blue channel value trying to apply Sobel Operator for edge detection

Tags: c, filter, cs50, sobel

So I have been trying to write a function that implements the Sobel Operator on a bitmap image as part of an assignment for CS50.

The thing I've been struggling with last couple of hours is identifying what is wrong with my code in implementing this function as it correctly produces the values for the Red and Green Channel but does so incorrectly for the Blue Channel.

I am attaching the image of the error message I get from CS50 when i run the `check50 cs50/problems/2024/x/filter/more` prompt at the command line which checks the code I've written against test cases written by CS50.

[Failed Test Cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnxgG.png)

I am attaching a link to the assignment below. You may have to scroll down a bit to get to the 'edge' section of the assignment where the finer details of the assignment are explained in relation to the edge detection implementation of the function.

As you might have already guessed by now, I am a total newbie to programming so really any help will be greatly appreciated! Also, please excuse me If I have not taken any steps people normally would in making the code more readable.

Link to the assignment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2024/psets/4/filter/more/

I have pasted the function I've written so far. For some reason, it produces the correct values for the Red and Green Channel but does so incorrectly for the Blue channel.

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int Gx_Matrix[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int Gy_Matrix[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    // Create a copy of the originial image //
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Loop over each pixel //

    // Calculate the weighted sum of each colour channel //

    // Combine the Gx and Gy weight sum to attain a single value for each channel //

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float Gx_SumRed = 0;
            float Gy_SumRed = 0;
            float Gx_SumGreen = 0;
            float Gy_SumGreen = 0;
            float Gx_SumBlue = 0;
            float Gy_SumBlue = 0;

            for (int di = -1; di <= 1; di++)
            {
                for (int dj = -1; dj <= 1; dj++)
                {
                    int ni = i + di;
                    int nj = j + dj;

                    if((ni >= 0) && (ni < height) && (nj >= 0) && (nj < width))
                    {
                        Gx_SumRed += Gx_Matrix[di + 1][dj + 1] * (copy[ni][nj].rgbtRed);
                        Gx_SumGreen += Gx_Matrix[di + 1][dj + 1] * (copy[ni][nj].rgbtGreen);
                        Gx_SumBlue += Gx_Matrix[di + 1][dj + 1] * (copy[ni][nj].rgbtBlue);

                        Gy_SumRed += Gy_Matrix[di + 1][dj + 1] * (copy[ni][nj].rgbtRed);
                        Gy_SumGreen += Gy_Matrix[di + 1][dj + 1] * (copy[ni][nj].rgbtGreen);
                        Gy_SumBlue += Gy_Matrix[di + 1][dj + 1] * (copy[ni][nj].rgbtBlue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sqrt((Gx_SumRed * Gx_SumRed) + (Gy_SumRed * Gy_SumRed)));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sqrt((Gx_SumGreen * Gx_SumGreen) + (Gy_SumGreen * Gy_SumGreen)));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sqrt((Gx_SumBlue * Gx_SumBlue) + (Gy_SumBlue * Gy_SumBlue)));

            if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
            }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I also understand that I need to produce a minimally reproducible piece of code. Since CS50 has separated this function from the main implementation of the rest of the program as helper functions, you may need to download the distribution code for the remaining program. You can do so by running the following prompt at the command line:

`wget https://cdn.cs50.net/2023/fall/psets/4/filter-more.zip`

You can find the function itself in a file called `helpers.c`.

I don't know if this is particularly insightful, but in the test cases written by CS50, the correct blue channel values is 255. I am not sure if the code I've written only produces the wrong value when the correct value is 255 or if it produces the wrong value for other cases as well when the correct Blue channel value isn't 255.

I did check my code to prevent value overflow from occurring whenever the returning value exceeds 255 to cap it at 255. I don't see any errors in the implementation for that as well.

Comment: Why are you using (squishy) `float` variables when RGB intensity values are `int` (or `unsigned char`, actually)? The `sqrt()` operation will be done with `float` but that is the only use of that datatype...

Comment: How are you calling the function and how was the parameters declared & allocated?

Comment: @Fe2O3 It uses `double` even. `sqrtf` uses `float`.

Comment: Please provide text messages as text in your question, not as pictures. This includes error messages from your checker as well. Please also provide more useful error descriptions. The test cases in CS50 hold way more information about test data, expected result and incorrect result. That should be included into the question as well.

Comment: `if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)` Please step back and think about what you are doing here. Why do you want to limit the value at 255? Hint: You do it because the RGB values can only hold 8 bits, i.e. value up to 255. If you do this here, then it is too late. You cannot prevent an overflow after it has happened.

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you so much for that prompting me to think rather than just give me a solution. I modified the code to prevent overflow from happening using a conditional and it worked. This made me realise how it's critical to think from first principles. I'm a newbie but hope to keep getting better everyday! Thank you so much once again :)